# How do I connect my external hard drives to the local house network?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, wireless-networking, mac, bluetooth

I have about 10 4TB western digital hard drives of various shapes and sizes which are all plugged into a large 16 port USB hub which I can then connect to my MacBook Pro laptop. But it's a pain because I have to be physically near them, while I instead like to move around while on my laptop.

How can I make it so I can access these "through the cloud" somehow? Without having to upload everything on them to the internet like to Google Drive. What is the general approach to this? Is it BlueTooth? Wifi? I don't know much about these technologies, so just wondering what approach to take and generally where to go looking for specifics on how to do it. (I'm a software developer, but don't know much about networking).

Basically, I have a router/network thing from my service provider, and that's about it. I don't know what to do next, do I need to setup a local wifi network or something, or can I somehow just turn on some bluetooth hub which I may have to buy, and plugin all hard drives, and viola?

Thanks for the help. Knowing this would greatly simplify my amateur quest of making use of large sets of open data on my home laptop. I would like to move away from this "legacy" system of manually plugging into external hard drives, and figure out how to get it wireless.

Comment: You'll need a server of some sort. Can be a NAS or another computer. Given that these are USB drives and not real drives, a NAS is not going to work if you want to make these drives portable. In that case you really do need another computer, plug the drives in and share it. If you can get the drives out of the housing, then a NAS is the way to go.

Comment: Most NAS systems I know of (and even many of the more advanced routers) allow attaching external USB drives to share them on the network. I don’t know if they would support 10 at the same time though.

Comment: You should be able to just use an Raspberry Pi with an active USB Hub to prevent any issues with the power. On the raspberry you can install some open source software like nextcloud. These steps require some basic skills of linux but are also explained in many tutorials (one I found is this: https://youtu.be/O-FfOWdZAQ4)

Comment: What's your budget, and speed expectations?  A raspberry Pi 4 8gb (for caching,probably excessive)  is $55 and right around $100 for a kit. However, your going to be limited to about 120mb/s total.  If money is no object, shuck the drives, by a case mount all of them in case with a fancy RAID 6 controller card with a 10gb NIC.